# Best tricks to handle my data in Machine learning(binary classification)?

Tags: python, validation, csv, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm a newbie to machine learning please forgive me if I'm dumb.
I have a traindata.csv file with 22 attributes and 30000 data points.

I have to train my model(not specific algorithm) and predict on 20000 data points in testdata.csv file on which I have to make predictions with my trained model.

In traindata.csv, the ratio of '0' and '1' class labels is 5:1.
If I train my model with this whole train data, my model shows some bias towards predicting 0's than 1.

I somehow know that the actual values in my test data are 0's and 1's in the ratio of 1:1.

Can you suggest me some method(some sort of noise cancellation) to preprocess my train data such that there will be no bias towards 0's while predicting on my test data(as it has equal 0's and 1's)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classical problem called "imbalanced classification"

I would suggest a Balanced Bagging Classifier. If you like python I would recommend [this](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/imbalanced-learn/stable/generated/imblearn.ensemble.BalancedBaggingClassifier.html). I does not really matter what you Bag but trees are a good place to start. There is a lot of documentation and other methods in this package.

If you want to be a little more fancy you can use [Hellinger distance](https://www3.nd.edu/~nchawla/papers/DMKD11.pdf) in any type of tree method. Standard trees choose split points which are sensitive to the ratio of class sizes (ie skew). The Hellinger distance is not. I do not know of an open source implementation in python.

Comment: Thanks, but can you suggest something similar to 'BalancedBaggingRegressor ' as in the link you provided [link](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/imbalanced-learn/stable/generated/imblearn.ensemble.BalancedBaggingClassifier.html) as im using regression models??

Comment: You talked of class labels, so you are doing classification. If you have enough classes and they are ordinal then it is the same as regression. If this is the case then there is nothing I can offer you. I am not aware of any research around the density of training events in the target dimension. I high suggest you reword your question. Make it more formal and try and use technical terms. Existing code would help too. What model are you using?

Comment: I am using "XGBRegressor" I have only two class labels '0' and '1' . My training data is so worse as I described above.So I want to give something like class_weight = "balance" so Im asking for 'BalancedBaggingRegressor '

Comment: I repeat. If you have two classes you are doing classification not regression. ie trying to predict 1 or 0 not a point in the range (0,1) Try  sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier

Comment: Actually, Im doing a kaggle contest which gives results based on auc score , so I can submit predicted probabilites also in that case so that I can get good aucscore .So thats why im using XGBRegressor.

Comment: If you want a AUC for the ROC you are doing binary classification. 100% for sure. The predict_proba() method will give you your probability. DO NOT USE REGRESSION.